# Ember + Mirage: response mock errors

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

```js
  // Some code from router
  return user.save().catch(e => {
    debugger; // says: ErrorClass {isAdapterError: true, stack: "Error: The adapter rejected the commit because it was invalid}
  });

  // Test
  import { Response } from 'miragejs';

  test('Show error page when failed uniqueness validation', async function(assert) {
    server.post('/users', () => {
      return new Response(422, {}, { errors: [{ detail: 'has already been taken' }] });
    });

    await visit('/users/new?email=test@email.com');
  });
```

I'm using Ember `3.16` and ember-cli-mirage `1.1.8`. I have a test which is not working properly. I'm mocking a 422 Response from mirage. This response also contains some errors. In the router, where the request is made, the request fails (enters the `catch`) but when I inspect the error it doesn't tell me the status code or the details of it

Comment: Do you .catch() in your app code? You might be seeing an Ember Data error

Answer (score 0):

looking at the documentation from emberCLI Mirage V1.1.8, it shows this [example](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/testing/acceptance-tests#testing-errors) to test errors

```
test('the user sees an error if the save attempt fails', async function(assert) {
   this.server.post('/questions', () => ({
     errors: [ 'The database went on vacation' ]
   }), 500);

   await visit('/');
   await click('.new');
   await fillIn('input', 'New question');
   await click('.save');

   assert.dom('h2').hasText('The database went on vacation');
});
```

it's a different syntax to specify the error and the status response

Comment: Using the `Response` class, which is documented [here](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/api/modules/response~Response) is also valid.